# BeautifulSoup: Finding other elements after locating a div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Inside a page, I have the following HTML

```
<div class="ProfileDesc">
<p>
    <span class="Title">Name</span>
    <span>Tom Ready</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span class="Title">Born</span>

<span>
    <bxi> 10 Jan 1960</bxi> 
<p>
    <span class="Title">Death</span>
    <span>
        <bxi> 01 Jun 2019</bxi>
    </span>
</p>
</div>
```

The following code works for extracting the ProfileDesc from the whole page

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "ProfileDesc"})
```

I want the following output

```
Name: Tom Ready
Born: 10 Jan 1960
Death: 01 Jun 2019
```

How do I extract these after finding the ProfileDesc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're pretty sure about the DOM structure:

```py
mydivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "ProfileDesc"})

for element in mydivs.find_all("p"):
    title = element.find("span")
    content = title.findNext("span")
    print("%s : %s" % (title.text.strip(), content.text.strip()))
```

Output:

```sh
Name : Tom Ready
Born : 10 Jan 1960
Death : 01 Jun 2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html code after " 10 Jan 1960 " has no end p tag

```
name = soup.find('span',string='Name').parent.text.replace('Name','').strip()
born = soup.find('span',string='Born').parent.text.replace('Born','').strip()
death = soup.find('span',string='Death').parent.text.replace('Death','').strip()
print(f'Name: {name}')
print(f'Born: {born}')
print(f'Death: {death}')
```

Comment: What is the `f` in f'Name:{name}'?

Comment: f-Strings - An Improved String Formatting Syntax
(https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
keys_ = set() # avoid duplicate keys

for p in mydivs.find_all("p"):
    ss = list(p.stripped_strings)

    for k, v in zip(ss[::2], ss[1::2]):
        if k in keys_:
            continue
            
        keys_.add(k)
        print(k, ":", v)
```

---

```
Name : Tom Ready
Born : 10 Jan 1960
Death : 01 Jun 2019
```